# How to rotate an SVG 45 degrees in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

So I have the url to an SVG that I get from an API generating QR codes and the SVG is the image for the QR code. I cannot seem to figure out the best way to rotate this SVG 45 degrees, I have tried getting the svg url making an axios call to get the text data then trying to rotate from there should i convert it to a PNG or so it appears SVGToImg is not a function I thought it was but the library I guess does not have such. Here is what I have tried just now but have not been successful. My libraries are at the top of the code. This is on the server side of my codebase I want to rotate the image and store it in the database I have connected.

code:

```
 const { createCanvas } = require("canvas");
    const svg2img = require("svg2img");
    const svgToImg = require("svg-to-img");

const qrCodeSvgUrl = qrCodeData.data.qr_code;
// Fetch SVG content
const svgResponse = await axios.get(qrCodeSvgUrl, { responseType: "text" });
console.log("svg response = ", svgResponse.data);
const qrCodeSvg = svgResponse.data;

// Convert SVG to PNG
const pngBuffer = await svgToImg(qrCodeSvg, { format: "png" });

// Create a canvas and load PNG buffer
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200); // Adjust size as needed
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new canvas.Image();
img.src = pngBuffer;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Rotate the canvas by 45 degrees
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
ctx.rotate((45 * Math.PI) / 180);
ctx.drawImage(img, -canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);

// Convert canvas back to PNG
const rotatedPngBuffer = canvas.toBuffer();
console.log("rotated svg url to visit = ", rotatedPngBuffer);
qrCodeData.data.qr_code = rotatedPngBuffer;
```

Comment: It's an SVG image. Just... put it in an `<img>` element and set `transform: rotate(45deg)` using CSS? (with the transform origin at the center)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just save the SVG in the database or where ever as it is. Let's say that, in the future, you would like to rotate the image 38 degrees or have a larger image (now, that it is a PNG).

You don't need to manipulate or convert the SVG. The following examples are using the same SVG (an orange rectangle) to show different ways of rotating the SVG, either by referring to the SVG as a URL or embedding the SVG directly in the HTML.

You could rotate the image using CSS:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  padding: 35px;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIgZmlsbD0ib3JhbmdlIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=">
```

Or wrap the SVG in another SVG and then rotate it:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="270" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image transform="translate(15 15) rotate(45 35 35)" width="70" height="70"
    href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIgZmlsbD0ib3JhbmdlIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=" />
</svg>
```

Or you can just insert the SVG element inline and use CSS to rotate:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  padding: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="orange" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Or append the SVG element in another SVG and then add the transform attribute:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="270" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg transform="translate(15 15) rotate(45 35 35)" width="70" height="70"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="orange" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: this is server side code that I am trying to rotate the image on and then store it in my mongo db not client side html tags. Can you revise the answer?

Comment: But remember to specify the transform-origin. You don't want to rotate relative to (0,0).